# Keep float element at the bottom

Tags: html, css

There is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/a4Le1jkz/.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-container">
<form action="#" method="#" id="form">
    <input type="image" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1439918200-send.png" alt="Send" id="send" class="send" />
    <div class="twrap">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows=1></textarea></div>
   </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;   
    width: 100%; 
    color: white; 
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 10px;
}
.form-container .twrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.form-container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    max-height: 120px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    resize : none;
}

.form-container .send {
    padding: 3px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
}
```

I'd like to keep the image at the bottom of the `textarea` even though the user presses **Enter**. The `textearea` has to continue to adjust its width.

The image is floating so I don't know how to keep it at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the `.send` in `position: absolute; bottom:10px; right:15px`

and set the width of the textarea to make sur they don't overlap.

Here a update to your JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4Le1jkz/1/

Edit:
here a update: https://jsfiddle.net/a4Le1jkz/7/ i set `width: 100%` to the textarea and i add to the .twrap  `padding-right` equal to the place i need for the image at the right.

Comment: When you resize the window, the textarea and the image overlap.

Comment: Setting the `width` of the textarea isn’t really helpful, because it should be 100% minus the width of the image. You could fix that with CSS `calc()`, but a lot of browsers don’t support that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you set on using `float: right` or would you be open to `display: inline-block;`. With a little tweaking, I was able to get this to work using the `display` option.

```js
/*!
 Autosize 3.0.8
 license: MIT
 http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize
*/
!function(e,t){if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define(["exports","module"],t);else if("undefined"!=typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)t(exports,module);else{var o={exports:{}};t(o.exports,o),e.autosize=o.exports}}(this,function(e,t){"use strict";function o(e){function t(){var t=window.getComputedStyle(e,null);"vertical"===t.resize?e.style.resize="none":"both"===t.resize&&(e.style.resize="horizontal"),u="content-box"===t.boxSizing?-(parseFloat(t.paddingTop)+parseFloat(t.paddingBottom)):parseFloat(t.borderTopWidth)+parseFloat(t.borderBottomWidth),i()}function o(t){var o=e.style.width;e.style.width="0px",e.offsetWidth,e.style.width=o,v=t,l&&(e.style.overflowY=t),n()}function n(){var t=window.pageYOffset,o=document.body.scrollTop,n=e.style.height;e.style.height="auto";var i=e.scrollHeight+u;return 0===e.scrollHeight?void(e.style.height=n):(e.style.height=i+"px",document.documentElement.scrollTop=t,void(document.body.scrollTop=o))}function i(){var t=e.style.height;n();var i=window.getComputedStyle(e,null);if(i.height!==e.style.height?"visible"!==v&&o("visible"):"hidden"!==v&&o("hidden"),t!==e.style.height){var r=document.createEvent("Event");r.initEvent("autosize:resized",!0,!1),e.dispatchEvent(r)}}var r=void 0===arguments[1]?{}:arguments[1],d=r.setOverflowX,s=void 0===d?!0:d,a=r.setOverflowY,l=void 0===a?!0:a;if(e&&e.nodeName&&"TEXTAREA"===e.nodeName&&!e.hasAttribute("data-autosize-on")){var u=null,v="hidden",f=function(t){window.removeEventListener("resize",i),e.removeEventListener("input",i),e.removeEventListener("keyup",i),e.removeAttribute("data-autosize-on"),e.removeEventListener("autosize:destroy",f),Object.keys(t).forEach(function(o){e.style[o]=t[o]})}.bind(e,{height:e.style.height,resize:e.style.resize,overflowY:e.style.overflowY,overflowX:e.style.overflowX,wordWrap:e.style.wordWrap});e.addEventListener("autosize:destroy",f),"onpropertychange"in e&&"oninput"in e&&e.addEventListener("keyup",i),window.addEventListener("resize",i),e.addEventListener("input",i),e.addEventListener("autosize:update",i),e.setAttribute("data-autosize-on",!0),l&&(e.style.overflowY="hidden"),s&&(e.style.overflowX="hidden",e.style.wordWrap="break-word"),t()}}function n(e){if(e&&e.nodeName&&"TEXTAREA"===e.nodeName){var t=document.createEvent("Event");t.initEvent("autosize:destroy",!0,!1),e.dispatchEvent(t)}}function i(e){if(e&&e.nodeName&&"TEXTAREA"===e.nodeName){var t=document.createEvent("Event");t.initEvent("autosize:update",!0,!1),e.dispatchEvent(t)}}var r=null;"undefined"==typeof window||"function"!=typeof window.getComputedStyle?(r=function(e){return e},r.destroy=function(e){return e},r.update=function(e){return e}):(r=function(e,t){return e&&Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length?e:[e],function(e){return o(e,t)}),e},r.destroy=function(e){return e&&Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length?e:[e],n),e},r.update=function(e){return e&&Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length?e:[e],i),e}),t.exports=r});
autosize($('#message'));
```

```css
.form-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;   
    width: 100%; 
    color: white; 
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 10px;
}
  
.form-container .twrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
}

.form-container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    max-height: 120px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize : none;
}

.form-container .send {
    padding: 3px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
    <form action="#" method="#" id="form">
        <div class="twrap">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows=1></textarea>
        </div><input type="image" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1439918200-send.png" alt="Send" id="send" class="send" />
   </form>
</div>
```

The following changes were made:

**HTML:**

The `<div class="twrap">` was moved before the input.

**CSS:**

`display: inline-block;` and `width: 90%` were added to the `.form-container .twrap` CSS.

`display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: bottom;` were added to the `.form-container .send` CSS. In addition, `float: right;` was also removed from this CSS.

Comment: this is a good one but it won't work very good on different resolutions. I think the position absolute solution provides the most flexibility in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox you will easily achieve what you want like this:

```js
/*!
 Autosize 3.0.8
 license: MIT
 http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize
*/
! function (e, t) {
    if ("function" == typeof define && define.amd) define(["exports", "module"], t);
    else if ("undefined" != typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module) t(exports, module);
    else {
        var o = {
            exports: {}
        };
        t(o.exports, o), e.autosize = o.exports
    }
}(this, function (e, t) {
    "use strict";

    function o(e) {
        function t() {
            var t = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
            "vertical" === t.resize ? e.style.resize = "none" : "both" === t.resize && (e.style.resize = "horizontal"), u = "content-box" === t.boxSizing ? -(parseFloat(t.paddingTop) + parseFloat(t.paddingBottom)) : parseFloat(t.borderTopWidth) + parseFloat(t.borderBottomWidth), i()
        }
        function o(t) {
            var o = e.style.width;
            e.style.width = "0px", e.offsetWidth, e.style.width = o, v = t, l && (e.style.overflowY = t), n()
        }
        function n() {
            var t = window.pageYOffset,
                o = document.body.scrollTop,
                n = e.style.height;
            e.style.height = "auto";
            var i = e.scrollHeight + u;
            return 0 === e.scrollHeight ? void(e.style.height = n) : (e.style.height = i + "px", document.documentElement.scrollTop = t, void(document.body.scrollTop = o))
        }
        function i() {
            var t = e.style.height;
            n();
            var i = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
            if (i.height !== e.style.height ? "visible" !== v && o("visible") : "hidden" !== v && o("hidden"), t !== e.style.height) {
                var r = document.createEvent("Event");
                r.initEvent("autosize:resized", !0, !1), e.dispatchEvent(r)
            }
        }
        var r = void 0 === arguments[1] ? {} : arguments[1],
            d = r.setOverflowX,
            s = void 0 === d ? !0 : d,
            a = r.setOverflowY,
            l = void 0 === a ? !0 : a;
        if (e && e.nodeName && "TEXTAREA" === e.nodeName && !e.hasAttribute("data-autosize-on")) {
            var u = null,
                v = "hidden",
                f = function (t) {
                    window.removeEventListener("resize", i), e.removeEventListener("input", i), e.removeEventListener("keyup", i), e.removeAttribute("data-autosize-on"), e.removeEventListener("autosize:destroy", f), Object.keys(t).forEach(function (o) {
                        e.style[o] = t[o]
                    })
                }.bind(e, {
                    height: e.style.height,
                    resize: e.style.resize,
                    overflowY: e.style.overflowY,
                    overflowX: e.style.overflowX,
                    wordWrap: e.style.wordWrap
                });
            e.addEventListener("autosize:destroy", f), "onpropertychange" in e && "oninput" in e && e.addEventListener("keyup", i), window.addEventListener("resize", i), e.addEventListener("input", i), e.addEventListener("autosize:update", i), e.setAttribute("data-autosize-on", !0), l && (e.style.overflowY = "hidden"), s && (e.style.overflowX = "hidden", e.style.wordWrap = "break-word"), t()
        }
    }
    function n(e) {
        if (e && e.nodeName && "TEXTAREA" === e.nodeName) {
            var t = document.createEvent("Event");
            t.initEvent("autosize:destroy", !0, !1), e.dispatchEvent(t)
        }
    }
    function i(e) {
        if (e && e.nodeName && "TEXTAREA" === e.nodeName) {
            var t = document.createEvent("Event");
            t.initEvent("autosize:update", !0, !1), e.dispatchEvent(t)
        }
    }
    var r = null;
    "undefined" == typeof window || "function" != typeof window.getComputedStyle ? (r = function (e) {
        return e
    }, r.destroy = function (e) {
        return e
    }, r.update = function (e) {
        return e
    }) : (r = function (e, t) {
        return e && Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length ? e : [e], function (e) {
            return o(e, t)
        }), e
    }, r.destroy = function (e) {
        return e && Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length ? e : [e], n), e
    }, r.update = function (e) {
        return e && Array.prototype.forEach.call(e.length ? e : [e], i), e
    }), t.exports = r
});
autosize($('#message'));
```

```css
.form-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
#form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.form-container .twrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.form-container textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    max-height: 120px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize : none;
}
.form-container .send {
    padding: 3px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
    <form action="#" method="#" id="form">
        <div class="twrap">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows=1></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="image" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1439918200-send.png" alt="Send" id="send" class="send" />
    </form>
</div>
```

[Here a working jsfiddle to play with.](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/haotszon/1/)

Comment: I’m not the one who downvoted — seems like a robust solution to me. My guess is that the reason for the downvote is the lack of broad browser support of the flexbox technology, however.

Comment: @Xufox I think that it is not a reason to down vote the answer and check this for the browser  support https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#browser-support, all modern browser support it.

Comment: The table that you linked to doesn't show it but IE 10 only supports a partial implementation of the _flex box layout module_ based on the 2012 standard. [Reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). IMO, that's still note a reason to downvote the answer though.

Comment: @Yandy_Viera Well… IE is a bit difficult as usual… but other than that, I’m not sure either, why you were downvoted. I actually upvoted you… But you got 3 upvotes anyway. Nothing to worry about, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just use a table instead of divs. The table cell can have a `vertical-align:bottom` CSS value.

```
<div class='form-container'>
    <form action="#" method="#" id="form">
        <table style='width:100%'>
            <tr>
                <td class="twrap"><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></td>
                <td style='vertical-align:bottom'><input type="image" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/34/1439918200-send.png" alt="Send" id="send" class="send" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may work, keep in mind that tables are meant for tabular data, not for layouts.

Comment: A CSS table should be used instead of an HTM one.